# Flex 4 Remote Object Method

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, remoteobject

I post this previously in Adobe Forum but haven't got any answers so far.

How do I do this in Flex 4?

```
 <mx:RemoteObject id="srv" destination="product" channelSet="{channelSet}"
 fault="faultHandler(event)">
   <mx:method name="getProducts" result="getProducts_resultHandler(event)"/>
 </mx:RemoteObject>
```

I got

> Could not resolve `<s:Method>` to a component implementation.

When trying to do this

```
 <s:RemoteObject id="roMajor"
   destination="MajorSrv"
   fault="Alert.show('Remote Object Error')" >
     <s:Method name="AddMajor" result="roMajorResult(event)"/>
 </s:RemoteObject>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `<RemoteObject/>` tag into `<fx:Declarations>` tag:

```
<fx:Declarations>
  <s:RemoteObject id="roMajor" destination="MajorSrv" 
    fault="Alert.show('Remote Object Error')">
      <s:method name="AddMajor" result="roMajorResult(event)"/>  
  </s:RemoteObject>
</fx:Declarations>
```

The following is taken from [RIA Zone](http://ria.dzone.com/news/flex-3-and-flex-4-beta-how-are?page=0,1)

> In Flex 4, unlike its earlier versions, non-visual children that represent new property declarations are not allowed as immediate children of an Application. You can add these non-visual children under a `<fx:Declarations>` tag. This includes non-visual children such as effects, validators, formatters, data declarations, and RPC classes.

So practically anything that is not displayable (that doesn't extend *DisplayObject* (or **UIComponent** to be more flex specific)), should be added to the `fx:Declarations` tag, not as the direct child of root tag.

Comment: Umm.. Sorry, I forgot to mention that my RemoteObject tag was already inside fx:Declaration tag.

I could do this
<s:RemoteObject id="roMajorAdd" destination="MajorSrv" result="roMajorAddResult(event)" fault="Alert.show('Remote Object Error')" />

but I have to create one remote object for each operation that doesn't return the same type. What I wanted to do is use one remoteObject and configure it so that different method called would invoke different functions on result event.

So far I need to have one remote object for each SQL operations, it's tedious.

Comment: You are using *M*ethod instead of *m*ethod. Could that be the issue?